# Why does minimizing RSS(f) = $\sum_{i=1}^N(y_i - f(x_i))^2$ lead to infinitely many solutions

Tags: regression

Why does minimizing $$RSS(f) = \sum_{i=1}^N(y_i - f(x_i))^2$$ lead to infinitely many solutions?

I saw it from the book *The Elements of Statistical Learning,second edition (Chapter 2 section 2.7 under the topic Difficulty of the problem*. I don't really understand but trying to learn it. Also, I want to know a function that only has finite or single solution

Comment: They are infinitely many functions $f$ that passes through all of the points $(x_i,y_i)_{1\leq i \leq N}$ (you can draw infinitely many curves that goes through these points). Each one of this function will give $RSS=0$ and thus minimizes it.

Comment: @winperikle Please if I should understand, some of these curves can be linear and polynomial right ?

Comment: Yes.  But even so, there are still infinitely many polynomials that will have identical values at every one of the $x_i.$

Comment: @whuber  Please is it because of the squared that is why it has infinite solution or can I get an example of a function that has finite or one solution ?

Comment: @EALehn Draw any three dots on a page. How many curves can you draw that pass through all three dots?

Comment: @sycorax Many curves

Comment: Lagrange polynomials are an example how you can see that a polynomial is always able to pass through all points. And you can extend it such that infinitely many polynomials can pass through the points. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: @sextusEmpiricus I get it now

Comment: @EALehn You can write an Answer to your own question

Answer (score 2):

When you have $n$ points on a graph, there are many curves you can draw to pass through those $n$ points, provided no two points have a same $x$-coordinate and different $y$-coordinate.

Since RSS depends on the residuals in those points (which can be made zero by a curve that passes through the points), there will be many curves you can draw to make RSS = 0. Each of these curves serve as a solution to the function. That is why we have infinite number of solutions.

Comment: I have adapted your answer a bit. E.g. generalizing 3 points to $n$ points. Feel free to revert anything back which you don't like.

Comment: Do we still have infinite solutions of an input value has multiple output values e.g. regression on categorical variables? That we would not be able to achieve $RSS=0$ concerns me.

Comment: @Dave Yes. This answer is a little misleading because it is not necessary that all $x_i$ be distinct. Literally *any* function that passes through each point of the form $(x_i, \bar y_i)$ where $\bar y_i$ is the mean of the $y$ values of all data points of the form $(x_i,y)$ will minimize the sum of squared residuals, but it cannot possibly reduce the RSS to zero unless there is zero dispersion of those $y$ values. For instance, consider the dataset $(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0)$ and let $f$ be *any* function: the function $x\to x(1-x)f(x)$ minimizes RSS (equal to $2$) and every minimizer has this form.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where all the $x_i$ values are distinct (purely for simplicity) and suppose you set $f(x_i) = y_i$ at each point $i=1,...,n$.  Then you have $RSS(f) = 0$, which is minimised.  Now, if $n$ is finite then there are an infinite number of other points of $f$ that you didn't specify.  Since any specification of those other points leads to a valid minimiser, there are an infinite number of solutions to the minimisation.